# matrix report for leaves

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have `no.of days`, `start date` and `end date` stored in table to store no.of leaves of employees.

I want to create report in which user select start date and end date from calendar and report shows the data depending on date selected. But my problem is if the user select a date which is in between start date and end date, I want accurate no.of days for that particular employee.

for ex. the following data saved in database

> no of days 3
>
> start date 02/06/2016
>
> end date  04/06/2016

user selected start date `03/06/2016` and end date `04/06/2016` from calendar.
The expected result is: no. of days `2`

Please suggest a sql query or C# code

table structure

```
leaveId empid   leavetypeId     noofdays    startdate     enddate   
1            76         1             3         2016-06-02    2016-06-04
```

query i fired like as follows

```
select noofdays 
from table 
where startdate='2016-06-03' and enddate='2016-06-04'
```

and expected result

```
noofdays = 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table(s) DDL, some DML for sample data, and the desired result.

Comment: Did you tested bellow solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution:

```
DECLARE 
    @pStartDate DATE = {d '2016-06-01'}, -- p = parameter
    @pEndDate   DATE = {d '2016-06-12'}

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, x.CommonRangeStartDate, x.CommonRangeEndDate) + 1) AS NumOfCommonDays
FROM    (VALUES 
    (1, {d '2016-06-02'}, {d '2016-06-04'}),
    (2, {d '2016-06-02'}, {d '2016-06-02'}),
    (3, {d '2016-06-04'}, {d '2016-06-10'}),
    (4, {d '2016-06-12'}, {d '2016-06-15'}), 
    (5, {d '2016-06-14'}, {d '2016-06-17'}),
    (6, {d '2016-05-01'}, {d '2016-06-18'})
) s(LeaveID, StartDate, EndDate) -- I assume SD & ED's data type is DATE
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN s.StartDate >= @pStartDate THEN s.StartDate ELSE @pStartDate END AS CommonRangeStartDate, -- MAX
        CASE WHEN s.EndDate <= @pEndDate THEN s.EndDate ELSE @pEndDate END AS CommonRangeEndDate -- MIN
) x
WHERE s.StartDate <= @pEndDate
AND @pStartDate <= s.EndDate
```

Note #1: Assumptions: StartDate <= EndDate, @pStartDate <= @EndDate

Note #2: If you want to see details then use `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT SUM`